# BlackBerry advertising for Torch

Tags: blackberry

I downloaded the advertising SDK and followed the directions in the development guide PDF that came with the SDK.

This is what my code looks like after setting all the config stuff step by step in the PDF:

1. Banner bannerAd = new Banner("my zone id #", null);
2. bannerAd.setMMASize(Banner.MMA_SIZE_EXTRA_LARGE);
3. add(bannerAd);

When I have just lines 1 and 2 nothing happens, but when I put in line 3 my simulator will not start and it also does not work on an actual device. I am not getting exceptions and do not see anything weird in the event log.

The simulator I am running is a BlackBerry Torch, so is the actual device, and the advertising SDK is for post6.0 devices.

Comment: Have you tried running with the Bold 9900 simulator? I have found this to be much better when debugging apps which rely on external data e.g. from App World. Also it's *much* quicker to boot!

Comment: i haven't tired that, but i will. thank you :)